# Why is my coriander wilting?

Tags: cilantro

Planted the coriander seeds in two small glasses made up of glass. They were initially indoors. After sowing I would water it everyday. They started sprouting only after 8 days or so. They are just growing long stems and bending over. Eventually they started having two small leaflets. But now the thin stems are wilting, thinning from the bottom and they are dying . Please point out a solution.

Comment: They were placed indoors, would take them out for a couple of hours. Also tried to place them under a fibre sheet in a ventilated zone of the house so they could receive the warmth of the sun. After that I noticed they started thinning and dying stem by stem.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a photo of the seedlings? This may give you better answers. The [tour] and the [help] will explain more about how the site works. And while it’s good to add more information, it’s best to [edit] your original post, not post a comment, as comments are temporary by design.

Comment: Presumably these small glasses have no drainage holes, which isn't good - a photo would be helpful